# Subscribe and last value accessible notification structure when subscribed - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift

I need a library in Swift or an Rx solution.

I want to spread a listenable value in AppDelegate. From the screens that will occur after this value is spread, for example, when XController is created, I will subscribe to this value and I can get the newest values continuously. However, since the XController will be created after the first and only data is published in AppDelegate, I want to be able to get the last value when the data in AppDelegate is subscribed and do some operations if not nil. The detail is actually here.

Does anyone have a library or rx solution or any suggestions like this

Comment: What's wrong with simply asking the app delegate for the value when the controller is created?

Comment: @PhillipMills While the application is open, I cannot constantly query for a change in the runtime unless something triggers it. What happened there should trigger the event and I should be able to listen for this change in XController. As I have already explained in the question.

Comment: Listening is easy; you can post a notification, register callbacks, or use KVO.  I was responding to the part about XController needing to get an already existing value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this listener structure and listen in multiple places you want. Also, keep a global static value for listening on the next screens.

https://medium.com/better-programming/event-listeners-on-swift-867a239bb23b